# TypeScript Method Chaining – Return this – but only partially

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I would want to do simple chaining like

```js
class MyClass {
   methodA(): this {
      return this
   }
   methodB(): this {
      return this
   }
}

new MyClass()
   .methodA()
   .methodB()
```

but return only a part of the instance based on the calling function like

```js
class MyClass {
   methodA(): this {
      return this
   }
   methodB(): Omit<this, "methodA"> { // <- stop calling `methodA` after `methodB` was called
      // <- what to return?
   }
}

new MyClass()
   .methodA()
   .methodA()
   .methodB()
   .methodB()
   // .methodA() // <- cannot call `methodA` anymore
```

– how would I do this?

Sure, I could do

```js
   // typescript does not complain about this
   methodB(): Omit<this, "methodA"> {
      return {
         methodB: this.methodB
      } 
   }
   // but typescript would not complain about this either, weird
   methodB(): Omit<this, "methodA"> {
      return this // <- at least it let me do that without throwing 
   }
```

BUT what if I want to exclude a single method/property instead of including just a single one.

```js
   methodB(): Omit<this, "methodA"> {
      const { methodA, ...instance } = this // Could I destructure 'this'? typescript does not complain but eslint throws there would be a parsing error
      return instance
   }
```

Comment: I've seen this called a "fluent wizard" pattern. Essentially a fluent builder but you only allow some steps at a time and once you progress to a new stage, you have different methods available.

Comment: I guess you meant `const { methodA, ...instance } = this`? But that'll create a plain object, not a class instance, so it won't work.

Comment: The interface is what's important for the caller. The implementer may always provide additional methods. The `return this;` is simple and the way to go, nothing wrong with it.

Comment: If the consumer is also going to be TS, I would just return `this`,  yes, in JS land it will expose more functions but if your consuming use TS that should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the term »fluent wizard pattern« @VLAZ Didn't know how to call it, but it describes it quite well.
Thanks for your replies! – yes, there would be nothing wrong with just returning `this`. I am just curious if I could improve Developer Experience with those restrictions

Comment: Another problem with your single -> `methodB: this.methodB`,  `methodB` is going to loose it's context, unless your bind the outer `{}`..

Comment: I've never been a fan of function chaining, but using TS to implement this restrictive methods idea, it's certainly something I'll think about using in the future.  I knew there was a reason I hang around SO.. :)

Comment: Maybe someone should write up an answer here saying `return this` is the right approach and that producing something that lacks the method at *runtime* is almost certainly overkill unless someone can demonstrate a use case requiring it.  ... @Bergi? @lsc?

Comment: I can't really find a reference for "wizard builder". However, I did find something I've definitely read before which is ["staged builder"](https://medium.com/linagora-engineering/next-level-java-8-staged-builders-602530f68b75) (also "step builder"). The example is in Java but it's a similar concept. It's when you want a more straight forward path.

Comment: @jcalz yes, I agree; my use case is definitely not requiring it. (My class with chaining only produces json that must follow certain logical requirements. It's used only by other devs as a utility for fast prototyping and testing – normally a UI produces it. A parser however checks the json later in any way.) Just for a better Developer Experience … catch some possible bugs with typescript before the parser does at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface is all what is important for the caller. The implementation may always provide additional fields or methods that are not declared in the return type, that's basic structural subtyping - but the caller will know or care, and the autocompletion and typechecking will only use the declared return type.

So using `return this;` as an implementation is totally fine. Only if the library is consumed by JavaScript code (that is not typechecked) you can call those extra methods. If you really want to ensure that the builder pattern is followed and you have different appropriate methods at every step, use different classes for the fluent interface - and probably you'll want to create new instances with immutable fields anyway then. A factory function pattern might be suited better for that approach than `class` declarations though.